# Filter remote branches in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I’d like `git branch -a` to only show a subset of remote branches, e.g. branches that begin with prefix like 'origin/iliaskarim'

What is the nicest way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the other output you're trying to get rid of?  Maybe you want to show just remote branches (`git branch -r`)?  Are there branches being recorded that you just don't want (maybe you want master from several remotes, but not the branches)?  I think we need more information here.  There is no simple built-in filtering to match a pattern though.

Comment: git branch -a | grep origin*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
git branch -r --list origin/iliaskarim\*
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're in a bash context, just pipe (`|`) to a [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) ?

```
git branch -a | grep origin/iliaskarim
```

---

Then if you want *both* this subset of remote branches *and* all your local branches, maybe consider just chaining commands?

```
git branch -a | grep origin/iliaskarim; git branch
```

Comment: `git branch -r --list origin/iliaskarim\*`

Comment: @phd Hey I can't keep on profiting of your insight, estimated peer(s) :-) whip that answer out! (also, my brain is starting to melt and you guys lost me a mile ago on this one, I drop :-)

Comment: The main annoyance here is that for `git branch -a`, you pick one pattern (like `origin/iliaskarim*`) and you lose all the *local* branches. But if you're willing to run two commands (`git branch` and then `git branch -r`), and deal with the fact that for some reason, `-a` prints `remotes/origin/...` while `-r` prints `origin/...`, you'll be good here.

Comment: @torek What I don't get so far is why is it a problem to drop all local branches? Isn't it the goal to "only show a subset of **remote** branches"? (which here, I guess, refer to *remote-tracking* branches)

Comment: Well, the OP started with `git branch -a`. I think the goal was to show all local branches and a subset of remote-tracking names. It takes two commands to do this, no matter how you slice up the work. (Well, two `git branch` commands or one `git branch` and one `grep`.) Using `git for-each-ref` you can do it in one command, since for-each-ref is more flexible.

Comment: @torek With this other requirement, ok, but I admit I didn't spot it at all. I'll reread your answer in this light.

Answer (score 1):

The front end `git branch` command does not have an easy way to do this.

If you use a namespace-like prefix, though—such as `origin/iliaskarim/` (note the trailing slash)—`git for-each-ref`, which is the plumbing command that implements `git branch`, *does* have a nice way to do this.  In particular:

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin/iliaskarim
```

suffices to iterate over those names, and only those names.  You will still have to put this together with additional commands and/or options to get the effect of a limited `git branch -a`.

(Edit: as [phd notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054213/filter-remote-branches-in-git#comment96858442_55054240), you can also use a pattern match with an explicit glob-star: `refs/remotes/origin/iliaskarim*`, if you don't use a slash separator here.  Remember to protect the star from the shell, if using a shell.)

Using `grep -v` as a pipe to filter away names that include `remotes/origin/` but do not continue on with `iliaskarim` is another option.  (See [RomainValeri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55054240/1256452); the idea here is to invert the test, dropping branches that *do* match some regular expression.  Coming up with a suitable R.E., which depends on which expression syntax or syntaxes your grep supports, is left as an exercise. :-) )